# Phone Interview for Test Analyst Internship?

Tags: testing

I am getting a phone interview for an automated test analyst internship position at a bank. What questions would you think I would be asked?

Comment: Can you give us more details about what the position of "automated test analyst" is?

Comment: execute test cases based on test scripts; be responsible for ensuring that test cases and scripts are prepared and are reflective of approved business and test requirements, external design documents, as well as the processes and components for the project or initiative to which they are assigned

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming this is a test developer position.  I.e. you are developing test automation.  If so, I would expect two major sorts of questions:

1)  Programming questions.  See lots of other questions on SO for examples.  Figure out what language they use and brush up.

2)  Test questions.  these will be things like:
    How would you test a telephone, chair, rubber ball, etc.?
    How would you test a program (like notepad)?
The key to answering the second set of questions is to break it down into categories and exhaustively test each.  Test the main functionality.  Test the corner cases.  Test it for security, stress, etc.